# Word Completion C# VS2010

Tags: c#, intellisense, visual-studio-2010

I am having some issues with word completion in VS2010 running in windows 7. I have no word completion in C#, programming a web application.

The word completion works fine in html, but in code behind i need to use (alt + right) to see the completion options. Already checked the preferences and is all okay, also tried ctrl + alt + spacebar. No results.

Anyone know why is this happening?

Comment: Keep in mind that this is **Beta** ***1*** and a lot of things are not fully functional. Wait until Beta 2 and see if it still happens. I'm thinking that this will work correctly.

Comment: IntelliSense is not *word completion*. It's *auto completion*. Word completion is the sort of stuff Notepad++ does on "Ctrl+Enter", or Eclipse on "Alt+/". Is there a way to trigger *word* completion in VS2010?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved.

It wasn't active by default, but under Tools/Options/Text Editor/C#/General. Auto list members wasn't active...

Thanks for the answers!

Answer (score 1):

Does it happen only to your code or to any C# code? Try to crate a new empty C# project and see if it works. If it does not you can try to run VS from a command line with /resetsettings switch - this will reset all VS settings back to defaults. If it is still a no go you can try to re-install it

Answer (score 0):

Intellisense has many different items that cause the completion to not be available.  I would attempt the following  checks in descending order:

1. Are these any syntax errors occurring before the line(s) in question?
2. Has the required information been provided for that method/property/etc. been provided for that item? Mainly applies to custom developed code.
3. Do you have any 3rd party controls installed that may be doing something fancy for completion purposes.